# upload multiple images using wp_handle_upload

Tags: plugins, uploads

I have a form that users should upload multiple images but the code doesn't run correctly. This code works perfectly but when I add `foreach` to upload more images it doesn't work. it seems that `$_FILES` only gets the first image. I would be grateful if you could help.

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])){
    if(! function_exists('wp_handle_upload')){
        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    }
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES ['uploadfile'];
    $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false );
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, $upload_overrides);
    if($movefile && !isset($movefile['error'])){
        echo '<a href="'.$movefile['url'].'">view the link</a>';
    }else{
     echo '<p>'.$movefile['error'].'</p>';   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Can you edit your question to include the file inputs? Also, how is the above code called? Is it in a page template? REST endpoint? `functions.php`? A plugin? Which hook is it called on? Frontend or Backend? Also what does the foreach version look like?

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy people. Help them get to all the facts as soon as possible (without asking follow up questions) and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.